# Help to find method for solving combinatorial optimization problem/clustering

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory, optimization, operations-research

I am working on an application where the following problem has come up:

Given $N$ items and penalty matrix $A_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ where

$a_{ij} \in A_{ij}$

is the penalty for grouping item $i$ and item $j$ together.

The objective is to group the items in $k$ different groups such that the total penalty is minimized. I have formulated this as an optimization problem with binary variables

$y_{ij} = 1$ if item $i$ and item $j$ are grouped together

and objective function

$\min. z = \sum_{ij} A_{ij} y_{ij}$

The problem is that $A$ is very large and dense with the order of 900 million entries ($N$ = 30,000). The double index-variables (and associated constraints) make my algorithm run out of memory.

Is there a known OR/clustering problem similar to this, with an algorithm that runs in polynomial time? Or am I just using a poor formulation?

Thanks.

Comment: How big is $k$?  Is $A$ nonnegative?  Is $A$ completely dense?  If so, is the lowest value repeated a lot?

Comment: $k$ is an input parameter in the range 5-20 groups. $A$ is completely dense, with few repetitions. The entries are floats.

Comment: Are group sizes constrained (all groups must be the same size, or have between $g_0$ and $g_1$ elements)? Also, are you interested in heuristics or just exact solutions.

Comment: There are no constraint on group sizes. I don't need exact solutions, so heuristics are welcomed. I was hoping for this problem to be some sort of packing/partitioning problem that has been studied in the literature (with associated algorithms). However, I have not been able to identify this problem anywhere else, although it's applications seem very wide.

Comment: Have you looked into the literature on nonmetric clustering as there seem to be some papers and books on the subject, although I haven't checked them out? Also, have you tried just solving this with cplex or some other good solver? My guess is that wouldn't work but it's still worth trying since it's easy to do. I would imagine trying something like a simple greedy algorithm and then a simple randomized local search: pick k items at random and then do greedy to fill up the k clusters, then pick items at random and move them to the cluster that minimizes the objective value.

Comment: @ericf I tried to solve the problem as a MIP with CPLEX. Application crashes even for a much smaller problem than the one I am trying to solve. Also, I tried exactly what you are proposing as a greedy algorithm. The solutions are quite poor. Also, I didn't find any useful literature on nonmetric clustering. Unfortunately.

Comment: @GitHocray another approach is to think of this as community detection in a weighted network.  That's not really the same problem, but maybe some of the spectral and modularity based methods might help.  (This definitely feels like it should be a standard problem...)